# 2 Second Pendulum Length on The Moon

Tags: physics

This was a physics bonus assignment. I have been trying to solve it for the last 2 hours.
Let's say that the density of The Moon and The Earth are the same. Moon radius:Earth radius is $0.273:1$! How long does the pendulum have to be for the period ($T$) to be $2$ seconds.
We have the following constants available.

$$g(\text{Earth})=9.81m/s^2$$
$$G=6.67\times10^{-11}$$
I would really appreciate your help! This is not an obligatory assignment.

Comment: What is magnitude of gravity on the moon? Or specifically what is the ratio of gravity on earth to the moon?

Comment: We have none. I have tried to calculate it but it comes out wrong. BTW he said that we imagine the planets as a perfect sphere.

Comment: That is generally how physicists behave .. "Assume a perfect sphere". I will take a look at the problem.

Comment: Thank you Chinny and thank you KittyL for editing this for me. I am on my cellphone.

Comment: As this is clearly a physics question, I vote to transfer it to phys.st

Comment: Having worked on it for two hours (or more), surely you have identified a specific difficulty to ask about?  How did you approach the problem, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take the approximation
$$
T = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}
$$
for the moon we have to compute $g(\text{moon})$
$$
g(\text{moon}) = \frac{GM_{\text{moon}}}{r^2}
$$
this is the magnitude of the acceleration.
$$
M_{\text{moon}} = \rho V_{\text{moon}} = \rho \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3
$$
now since we know that density ($\rho$) is consistent between earth and moon we also have
$$
g(\text{earth}) = \frac{4}{3}\pi G\rho R_{e} \implies \rho =  \frac{g(\text{earth})}{\frac{4}{3}\pi G R_{e}}
$$
thus
$$
g(\text{moon}) = \frac{4}{3}\pi G r \frac{g(\text{earth})}{\frac{4}{3}\pi G R_{e}} \implies g(\text{moon}) = g(\text{earth})\frac{r}{R_e}
$$
thus we get
$$
T_{\text{moon}} = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g(\text{moon})}} = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g(\text{earth})\frac{r}{R_e}}}
$$
thus
$$

$$
L = g(\text{earth})\frac{r}{R_e}\frac{T_{\text{moon}}^2}{4\pi^2}\approx 0.0277 m
$$